# Why is my call stack size exceeded during this quicksort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

What is going wrong when i am trying to implement quicksort in JS ? I am getting a call stack size exceeded error.

```js
function quicksort(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 1)
    return arr;
  let pivot = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
  const left = [], right = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < pivot) {
      left.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else {
      right.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return quicksort(left).concat(pivot, quicksort(right));
}

console.log(quicksort([2, 5, 9, 5, 67, 1, 23, 9]));
```

Comment: Your `pivot` is an **index** into an array; it should be the value at that index.

Comment: Also a "real" quicksort is fast because it sorts in-place; it shouldn't create new arrays.

Comment: i changed the line to var pivot = arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2)]; but I am getting the same error

Comment: If you add some tracing you'll see that with that test data, it gets stuck on the sub-array `[2, 1]`.  That will result in an empty `left` array and a `right` array that is, again, `[2, 1]`, so the recursion never stops.

Comment: Even when corrected, "unconditional recursion" on both parts allows recursion on the bigger part, worst case take a depth of the original `arr.length`. I think recurring for the smaller part and iteration for the larger is [attributed to Sedgewick](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Optimizations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code builds the `left` and `right` arrays, that process *includes* the pivot value. Thus the total length of those two sub-arrays is the same as the overall length of the original array.

If you skip the pivot element, then the sort works (at least for your test case):

```js
function quicksort(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 1)
    return arr;
  let pp = Math.floor(arr.length / 2), pivot = arr[pp];
  const left = [], right = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i == pp) continue;
    if (arr[i] < pivot) {
      left.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else {
      right.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return quicksort(left).concat(pivot, quicksort(right));
}

console.log(quicksort([2, 5, 9, 5, 67, 1, 23, 9]));
```

As I noted in a comment above, one of the key features of quicksort among other good sorting algorithms is that it can be done with a constant space overhead. Real implementations do not create new sub-arrays. Instead, they rearrange elements in the original array. The recursion step includes start and end indexes instead of complete new arrays.

Comment: thanks a lot ! This works. I am just trying to get a feel for the algorithm before i implement the proper version. I also tried the following : var pivoy = arr.pop(); and it worked since i removed the pivot element.

Comment: Yes that would work too. Another possibility is to always choose element 0 and then start the `for` loop at 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [-6, 20, 8, -2, 4];

function swap(arr, i, j) {
    const temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

function partition(arr, low, high) {
    const pivot = arr[high];
    let i = low - 1;
    for (let j = low; j < high; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, i + 1, high);
    return i + 1;
}


function quick_sort(arr, low, high) {
    if (low < high) {
        const pivotIndex = partition(arr, low, high);
        quick_sort(arr, low, pivotIndex - 1);
        quick_sort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, high);
    }
}

const n = array.length;
quick_sort(array, 0, n - 1);
console.log("Sorted array:", array);
```

You should use this method as you don't want to create extra arrays while sorting.

Comment: Does this answer `What is going wrong…`?

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score -1):

it's maybe because your arr.length is less than one.

Comment: That is not possible in JavaScript.